# Edit webm video (with GUI)

Tags: video-editor, webm

I recorded a screencast with kazam.

Now I have a webm file.

Which tool can I use to edit this video?

I want to cut (remove) some parts.

I use Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

For cutting/inserting, a simple linear video tool like avidemux will do.

You may also use one of the several non-linear video editors available on Ubuntu. Openshot is very accessible for beginners, KDEnlive is very powerfull and still quite easy to master, and there are others.

That does not mean these editors support the webm format. Webm, hopwever, is just a container format that contains conventional audio and video streams. If necessary, you may need to transmux the video and audio to a container format supported by these formats. The Matroska format (.mkv) will certainly do. You can convert webm video to mkv video without any loss in quality using the command

```
ffmpeg -i file.webm -c:v copy -c:a copy fileout.mkv
```

This literally copies the video and audio streams, so it goes vast fast and there is no loss in quality. Simply providing the file extension .mkv is sufficient to tell ffmpeg to write out in Matroska format.

Answer (score 1):

[LosslessCut](https://mifi.no/losslesscut/) is another option for editing `webm` screencast files.

`ffmpeg` works. I've had more success explicitly setting fps:

> `ffmpeg -i "Screencast from 04-07-2023 03:24:55 PM.webm" -filter:v "fps=24" Apr0723.mkv`

The `webm` file created by **22.04**'s default screencast application lacks `Video Frame Rate` info. This throws off Blender and may do the same with KDEnlive and other video editors. Explicitly setting the frames per second with the command above avoids the issue.

I'm glad to have found this Question and Answer.