# Ubuntu 22.04 Screencast to mp4

Tags: 22.04, desktop-recording

I am rather happy with 22.04's new screenshot / screencast integration.

One thing though:

*Can we configure the screencast to output mp4 rather than webm files?*

Maybe another option would be a postprocessing script, but I don't see how one could trigger that automatically after the screencast is done.

Comment: I also need mp4... until then I will use Peek

Answer (score 1):

I am also happy with 22.04's screencast integration and need to work with output other than `webm`. For post-processing, `ffmpeg` works from the shell and the front-end with [LosslessCut](https://mifi.no/losslesscut/) and others.
I've had success explicitly setting fps in screencast `.webm` files:

> `ffmpeg -i "Screencast from 04-07-2023 03:24:55 PM.webm" -filter:v "fps=24" Apr0723.mp4`

**Apr0723.mp4** then works in VLC, Blender, others better than the screencast `.webm`.

Confirguring default screencast app re file formats and locations or to auto-trigger an `ffmpeg` script is research-in-progress for me including these AskUb threads:

- [How can I convert my webm screencast to mp4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460038/how-can-i-convert-my-webm-screencast-to-mp4)
- [Edit webm video (with GUI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153557/edit-webm-video-with-gui/)

Comment: How to record my voice using the 22.04's new screenshot / screencast integration?
Like for explaining what Im doing/recodrding to someone watching later