# How can I convert my webm screencast to mp4?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, webm

Gnome has a built-in screencast tool using `ctrl` plus `shift` plus `alt` plus `R`. It's a great tool with consistent quality video output!

But, I need the output in mp4. I have tried this: `ffmpeg -i screencast.webm -crf 0 screencast.mp4` as specified in other AskUbuntu posts, but it doesn't work well for me, even though it's supposed to be lossless.

My screencast in mp4 jumps around, freezes on a single frame, and the file sizes are drastically different.

I need h.264 mp4, ideally with a constant frame rate, at high definition.

What ffmpeg command can I use?

Here's an example file: `ffmpeg -i input.webm`

```
$ ffmpeg -i Screencast\ from\ 03-18-2023\ 04\:57\:59\ PM.webm 
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-libsmbclient
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Screencast from 03-18-2023 04:57:59 PM.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.20.3
    creation_time   : 2023-03-18T20:57:59.129336Z
  Duration: 00:16:48.47, start: 0.028000, bitrate: 858 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Can you post the command itself and subsequent full terminal output for this command: `ffmpeg -i screencast.webm` and then it should be a simple matter to suggest the appropriate FFmpeg command...

Comment: Updated! Thanks : )

Comment: Interestingly enough a VP8 video stream should be ok in an mp4 container so only *remuxing* is required: `ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v copy output.mp4` Support for VP8/9 in mp4 has been around a while but just check that your copy of FFmpeg is new enough to do this and that your playback application is also happy...

Comment: And what happens to frame rates? It's variable in webm, and I'd need constant in mp4, no?

Comment: I don't know. I would recommend a test run and see if FFmpeg will sort it out for you :). On a test encode here on my local machine there were no issues but best to test on your own setup...

Comment: The frame rate is precisely one issue. There's no frame rate specified in the default `[Screencast*].webm` and `Video Scan Type` comes across as *Unknown (2)* on my `22.04` setup. `ffmpeg` works when setting frame rate explicitly:  

`ffmpeg -i screencast.webm -filter:v "fps=30" screencast.mp4`

I've added more detail and options in my answer to this Q. Thank you, @andrew.46

Answer (score 7):

This works to output your screencast as an `mp4` that plays as expected in **VLC** and others:

> `ffmpeg -i screencast.webm -filter:v "fps=30" screencast.mp4`

This works in more cases and avoids `ffmpeg` throwing 'not divisible by 2' errors:

> `ffmpeg -i screencast.webm -filter:v "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,fps=30" screencast.mp4`

The above sets a constant frame rate of 30 frames per second (`fps`). It resizes your video by one pixel at most and makes sure your input width and height (`iw` and `ih`) are even numbers.

You can also specify codec options like `-codec:v libx264`. Check out [`ffmpeg`'s Video Options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) for your particulars.

Your questions and related Q&A I've found helpful during this research include these:

- [Ubuntu 22.04 Screencast to mp4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419122/ubuntu-22-04-screencast-to-mp4)
- [How can I convert my webm screencast to mp4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460038/how-can-i-convert-my-webm-screencast-to-mp4)
- [Edit webm video (with GUI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153557/edit-webm-video-with-gui/)
- (A gist that puts this whole answer into a handy ~/.bashrc function) https://gist.github.com/azeemh/de280db7ba71e1d69ed55c0e5855de50